# Select dropdown default value not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to web development. Before asking this question I have gone through all the solutions, but still I was getting some problems so...

Here I have HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label agency-label" for="agency">Agency :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4"> 
     <select id="selectAgency" 
        name="selectAgency" 
        class="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start candidateAgencyPosition"  
        ng-init="candidate.agency = agency[0]"
        ng-model="candidate.agency"
        ng-options="agencies for agencies in agency">
        <!--<option value="">Select Your Option</option>-->
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here I have an array:

```
$scope.agency = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
```

Now I want to have a A as a default value in that dropdown. But currently with this I am getting an empty value.

```
$scope.candidate = {
    noticePeriod: '',
    ctc: '',
    ectc: '',
    communication: '',
    agency: ''
};
```

This may be a duplicate but I am getting problem so I am asking. Thanks for 
the help.

Comment: I don't know Angular very well. Could it be because `agency: ''`?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize `ngModel` linked variable in the controller instead of using [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.agency = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
      $scope.candidate = {
        agency: $scope.agency[0]
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="candidate.agency" ng-options="agencies for agencies in agency"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ng-init and use ng-model instead:

Result:

```
$scope.candidate = {
    noticePeriod: '',
    ctc: '',
    ectc: '',
    communication: '',
    agency: 'A'
  };
```

Comment: actually my object is with $rootScope.candidate